# I'm unable to Login to VM with Azure AD user credentials

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rbac

I'm unable to login to Azure Virtual Machine with Azure AD credential even if select the Option Azure AD Domain Joined while creating the Azure VM.

I'm always getting **The Logon attempt failed** error.

Assigned Azure Virtual Machine Administration User role, but still unable to login to VM with Azure AD user.

Can someone fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to Login Azure VM with Azure AD Credentials, As I got same error.**

[image]

I have created Azure VM with **Login with Azure AD Option** while creating the Virtual Machine.

**Azure Portal > Virtual machines > Create**

[image]

Assign the RBAC role to user for login to VM with Azure AD Credentials.

**Assign any role to users.**

```
Virtual Machine Administrator Login- User assigned to this role,Can log in to Azure AD Admin privileges.
Virtual Machine User Login -User assigned this role,Can login in to normal user privileges.
```

**Azure Portal > Virtual machines > Access control (IAM) >Add >Add role assignment**

[image]

**Assigned Virtual Machine User Login role to User**

[image]

Verify **AADLoginForWindows** on Virtual Machine like below.

**Azure Portal > Virtual machines >Extensions + applications >Extensions**

[image]

**Join the VM to Azure AD Tenant and disconnect from existing AD Connect.**

[image]

[image]

Change the Remote Desktop Settings with **Network Level Authentication**,Like below

[image]

Assign user to **Remote Desktop Group** using below command.

```
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /add "AzureAD\u1@gopivallepuoutlook.onmicrosoft.com"

Ex: user VPN:Theja@Testdemo.onmicrosoft.com

Get-LocalGroupMember -Name "Remote Desktop users"
```

[image]

Modify the downlaoded RDP File with below Values and save the file.

```
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2
username:s:Theja@Testdemo.onmicrosoft.com (Add your username here)
domain:s:AzureAD
```

**Finally Logged in with Azure AD  (Theja )Credentials.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, Appreciate for your effort.