# How can i set logging into an azure vm by Entra Id (Active directory user)?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM and at the moment user login with a username and password via remote desktop.

I want to eliminate this and since the VM is in Azure make the users login with their Azure Active directory (Entra Id) user name and password.

How can i set this up ?

Answer (score 0):

To enable Microsoft Entra login for a Windows VM in Azure, you must first enable the Microsoft Entra login option for the VM and configure Azure role assignments for users who are authorized to log in to the VM. There are two ways to enable Microsoft Entra login for your Windows VM: through the Azure portal or Azure Cloud Shell.

To enable Microsoft Entra login for a Windows VM in Azure through the Azure portal, follow these steps:

1. Sign in to the Azure portal by using an account that has access to create VMs.
2. Create a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter VM in Azure with Microsoft Entra login by selecting Windows Server 2019 Datacenter from the Select a software plan dropdown list
   [image]
   and selecting the Login with Microsoft Entra ID checkbox in the Microsoft Entra ID section on the Management tab.
   [image]
3. Note- System assigned managed identity in the Identity section is selected. This action should happen automatically after you enable login with Microsoft Entra ID.
   [image]
4. Create an administrator username and password for the VM.
   [image]
5. Configure Azure role assignments for the VM to allow users to log in with their Microsoft Entra credentials. You will need to have these users created in Microsoft Entra id so that you can assign them these below permissions-

You will need below two roles-

```
Virtual Machine Administrator Login
```

[image]
and

```
Virtual Machine User Login
```

[image]

Verify  **AADLoginForWindows**  on Virtual Machine like below.

**Azure Portal > Virtual machines >Extensions + applications >Extensions**

[image]

Verify the VM is regisered to Azure AD Tenant
dsregcmd /status
[image]

Assign your user you created under entra id to  **Remote Desktop Group**
MyComputer->properties->enableRDP->Groups->RemoteDesktopUsers

[image]

Change the Remote Desktop Settings with  **Network Level Authentication unchecked**
[image]

Modify the downlaoded RDP File with below Values and save the file.

```
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2
username:s:<youruserprincipalname>
domain:s:AzureAD
```

**Finally Logged in with Azure AD (arko)Credentials.**
[image]

References:

- [Log in to a Windows virtual machine in Azure by using Microsoft Entra ID including passwordless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows#enable-microsoft-entra-login-for-a-windows-vm-in-azure)
- [Similar thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1497946/unable-to-login-with-entra-id-in-azure-ad-joined-v)
- [Similar Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74766839/im-unable-to-login-to-vm-with-azure-ad-user-credentials/74768619#74768619)

Comment: I alos access the vm via a url and port such as    https://<vm_ip_address>:2587.   Would it still require the user to use Entra Id or is there a different setup ?  On the port there is a service app running ?

Comment: In particular i am connecting to Jenkins , is it possible to use the entra id when using https://<vm_ip_address>:2587 to bring it up on a users browser ?

Comment: regarding accessing a service like Jenkins running on the VM via a URL and port, the Azure AD login for VMs is specifically for RDP access, not for HTTP access to applications like Jenkins. Both the questions are different. To secure Jenkins with Azure AD credentials, you will need to Create an enterprise application in Azure AD for Jenkins. Configure Azure AD Application Proxy to publish Jenkins securely. Configure Jenkins Security, Set up an authentication method that integrates with Azure AD, such as using the "Azure AD" plugin for Jenkins.