How can i configure AAD for an existing VM in Azure?
I have a VM in Azure that i created but didnt configure AAD. Where in the settings can i select the check box to make it AAD enabled ?
I have tried to look in settings and configuration to find the check box . But it only appears when you create a new VM ?

You can also configure the AAD for existing VM by using extension.
az vm extension set 
--publisher Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory 
--name AADLoginForWindows 
--resource-group myResourceGroup 
--vm-name myVM

I have done that , but when i login to the vm and run dsregcmd /status  , AzurADPort is NO , I thought it should be YES , also AzureAdJoined is NO ?

Restart the VM once execute the command.

I just did ... still the same

I am going to uninstall the extension and start again

Please check the extension status has succeeded or failed by visiting the extensions, here my result

did it again still says no ?

extension has succeeded

I just tested that if i create a new vm and select the checkbox it works , so i think the powershell command is not fully correct. The powershell command looks like it just adds the extension , I was wanting to enable the checkboxes ?

To enable the AAD for existing VM, first you need to enable System Managed Identity on the VM , like this  and uninstall the extensions, then restart the VM and install the extension. VM Join status in portal , dsregcmd /status result

Hope this helps to resolve your issue?

now do i install the extension via powershell or as below ?\

You can install using cli or portal, but before installing, enable the identity.

I think i will do cli as the portal has been running for over 5min ..?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

it now gives the correct screen .. ad login screen but when i try to login it says  "the sign in method you're trying to use isnt allowed . Try a different sign in method "

To login with Azure AD credentials, you need configure other things, follow the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74766839/im-unable-to-login-to-vm-with-azure-ad-user-credentials/74768619#74768619


How can i configure AAD for an existing VM in Azure

To enable Azure Active Directory for an existing virtual machine, you must first enable the System Managed Identity on the VM.

After enabling the identity, install the AADLoginForWindows extension. If the extension is already installed, uninstall it first.

Make sure to check the extension's status after installation.

The VM has been successfully joined to Azure AD. You can verify the result in the portal by navigating to Entra AD > Devices.

You can also check the Azure AD join status on the VM by running the dsregcmd /status

